# Connection to OneDrive issue in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive, powershell-4.0

I have this script running in VSCode but different $SiteURL. I open this script again in ISE and change the $SiteUR $searchfor and $folderpath. The issue I have is everytime I run in ISE and when it's doing Get-PnPListItem, it's getting an items from the path that I provided in the VSCode. Not sure what is going on so I would be really appreciated if I can get any help or suggestion.

```
$SiteURL = "https://companyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/user_id"
$searchfor  = "/personal/user_id/Documents/Pkmon"
$folderpath = "Documents/Pkmon"
$CSVFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Resource\FolderStats.csv"

#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -useWebLogin

$FolderItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $folderpath -PageSize 2000 -Fields ID, FileDirRef, FileRef -ScriptBlock `
    { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity `
            "Getting Items from Folder '$FolderServerRelativeURL'" -Status "Getting Items $global:Counter of $($List.ItemCount)"; }
 

$fieldvalues = $FolderItems.Fieldvalues

$result = @()
foreach ($field in $fieldvalues) {
    $obj = New-object psobject -property $field 
    $result += $obj.fileref
}

$final = $result | where-object {$_ -match $searchfor}

$item = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    FolderName     = Split-Path -Path $searchfor -Leaf 
    URL            = $searchfor 
    filesfoldercount = $final.count
}

$item 
$item  |  Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Did you remember to save the changes before executing the script?

Comment: Hi Mathias, Yes I did make sure to save the changes but still getting from the path that I provided in VScode.

Comment: Did you try disconnecting in VSCode first? [Disconnect-PnPOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/disconnect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps), or try `Get-PnPConnection | Disconnect-PnPOnline` at the top of your code

Comment: Hi @Theo I haven't cancel/disconnect the VSCode task yet because It's still executing. I was thinking about opening with ISE again so that I can execute different OD and speed up the process on what I'm trying to do. It's that maybe the reason why It's getting from the path in VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the connection object in a variable like

```
$thisConnection = Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -useWebLogin -ReturnConnection
```

<sup>`-ReturnConnection` acts as what is normally called `-PassThru`. It makes the cmdlet return the connection object for use with the -Connection parameter on other cmdlets.</sup>

Then use that in parameter `-Connection` of the `Get-PnpListItem` cmdlet:

```
$FolderItems = Get-PnpListItem -List $folderpath -Connection $thisConnection ...
```

You may also need to specify the connection in the VSCode instance.
When done, disconnect using `Disconnect-PnPOnline -Connection $thisConnection`